# Java GridLayout Image Size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I was making a program where it asks for your name and age and depending on your answer it would output a text phrase and an appropriate image but my problem is I cannot control the size of the components in my Grid layout so the picture is chopped off right at the top so I can only see a small portion

```
public class eb extends JFrame {

    private JLabel lblQuestion;
    private JLabel lblName;
    private JLabel lblAge;
    private JLabel lblAnswer;
    private JTextField txtName;
    private JTextField txtAge;
    private JButton btnEligible;
    private ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("H:\\NetBeansProjects\\Skill Set 15\\Egilible.jpg");
    private JLabel ImageEligible = new JLabel(image1);
    private ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("H:\\NetBeansProjects\\Skill Set 15\\Unegilible.jpg");
    private JLabel ImageUnegibile = new JLabel(image2);

    public eb() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 1)); 
        lblQuestion = new JLabel("Are you eligible to vote?");
        add(lblQuestion);
        lblName = new JLabel("Enter your Name");
        add(lblName);
        txtName = new JTextField(15);
        add(txtName);
        lblAge = new JLabel("Enter your Age");
        lblAge.setLocation(lblName.getX(), lblName.getY());
        add(lblAge);
        txtAge = new JTextField(15);
        add(txtAge);
        btnEligible = new JButton("Am I Eligible?");
        add(btnEligible);
        lblAnswer = new JLabel("Answer");
        add(lblAnswer);
        Eligible eligible = new Eligible();
        btnEligible.addActionListener(eligible);
    }

    public class Eligible implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int nAge = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText());
            String sName = txtName.getText();
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            if (nAge > 18) {
                lblAnswer.setText("Step right up " + sName + ", and vote. ");
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                c.gridheight = 10;
                JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
                p1.add(ImageEligible, c);
                add(p1, c);
            } else {
                lblAnswer.setText("Maybe next time, " + sName);
                JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
                p2.add(ImageUnegibile, c);
                add(p2);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I have so far, I'm trying to c to control height of the component thinking it will just make that portion bigger because the width is already fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get sizeof image by `getIconHeight()` and `getIconWidth()` then set size of JLabel with this values by calling `public void setSize(Dimension d)`, tell me if that worked.

Comment: I don't understand what would go into public void setSize(Dimension d), I don't know how to change the size

Comment: I sugested that you should get width and height of image, use it to create a Dimension object that you will pass to setSize of your JLabel, it will fix size of label to image size, it can help with your problem. Tell me if not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your answer in the same layout as the `GridLayout` for your form.  Put it in a place that it has room to stretch.

My suggestion for your situation would be:

- Put your form of labels and text fields in a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` for the LayoutManager.
- Set the contentPane of your frame to use a `BorderLayout`.
- Add the form to the "PAGE_START" of your contentPane.
- Add the answer to the "Center" of your contentPane.

Comment: My problem with this is when I use different panels I run into the problem of where my actionlistener goes.  My actionlistener needs things from the gridlayout and the other layout I choose to use.

Comment: Your actionListener can go whereever it makes sense.  It doesn't have to go in a panel.  If it needs access to variable in another Panel or class, create accessor methods to expose them or methods that the action listener can call that do the desired action.

Comment: How would I create an accessor method?

Comment: Example: public int getCount() { return count;}